# Transfer a voice memo in iPhone directly into Music app

Tags: iphone, itunes, voice-memo

I want to play the voice memos using Music app on my iPhone as it has a loop feature which the Voice Memos app doesn't.

But right now the only way I've been able to do it is by AirDropping from Voice Memos app to my Mac, then adding it to iTunes which sends it up to iCloud. Then go back to the iPhone and get the file in iTunes.

This can't be the most direct way to do it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible! You have to import them into your computer with iTunes or 3rd party apps. Then put them in music app.